# Htaccess make IMAGE to run as PHP or to read content from a PHP file

Tags: php, facebook, image, .htaccess

I have a file `image.php` with generate a jpeg image with `imagejpeg`. When somebody want to get a resized image or to crop, he opens `http://example.com/image.php?src=http://example.org/image`

Now I want this url to be accessible from `http://example.com/image.jpg?src=http://example.org/image`

I want to to this with htaccess, but i don't want to be a redirect, I want the image.jpg run as the image.php

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 image.jpg
```

but with no result.

I want to make this because when you want to add the picture in a facebook post, it isn't considered an image if is `image.php`

Thank you!

Comment: _“it isn't considered an image if is image.php”_ – I doubt that Facebook cares about “file extensions” in URLs. Are you sure you issued a correct `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps.

```
RewriteRule ^image\.jpg$ image.php [L]
```